# How to refer to Gauge Pointer's value from the expression for another Pointer's property?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS Report, I would like to set Hidden property of a Gauge Pointer when specific condition is met. How can I refer to Gauge Pointer's current value from the expression for Hidden property so that I do not have to duplicate the whole expression for Value?

This is what I mean (pseudo-code):

```
Hidden: =Code.GetHiddenPropertyBasedOnPointerValue(this.Value)
```

What should I use instead of "this.Value"?

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties of the Gauge Panel, go to the visibility section. Put the expression where it says "Show or hide based on an expression". Use an expression that evaluates to True for Hidden and False for Show.

Comment: This will hide or show the entire gauge, not just the gauge pointer.